# cannot set dynamic initial contents of a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview

I have the following segue in my storyboard, which connects to a ViewController, the root view of which is a `UICollectionView`

[image]

Following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9cZrAbxN1E

I created a similar setup of a `UICollectionViewController` with a custom dataSource. The main difference between his code, and my own, is that he immediately sets the dataArray of objects, which are mapped one to one on each collectionView cell, in `viewDidLoad` whereas I am grabbing them from asynchronous callback and setting the resulting objects in my dataSource array for my view cells.

The problem is that nothing is added to my View, after I follow the segue I show at the beginning. The main ViewController of the view pictured in the Storyboard is of type `FeedController`, so I know that is not why. I feel that it is because my contentSize isn't set properly perhaps. It is just weird because the person in the video never explicitly, to my knowledge, sets the size of his collectionView.

```
 import UIKit

let cellId = "cellId"


class FeedController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

var recipes = [BrowsableRecipe]()

var recipeIndex = 1
var pageSize = 10



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    navigationItem.title = "Homepage"

    collectionView?.alwaysBounceVertical = true

    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1)

    collectionView?.registerClass(RecipeCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)


    ServerMessenger.sharedInstance.getRecipesForHomePage(recipeIndex, pageSize: pageSize){
        responseObject, error in
        if let data = responseObject{

            self.recipes = data
            print(self.recipes)


        }

    }
}


override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return recipes.count
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let recipeCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(cellId, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RecipeCell
    print("cellForItem called")
    recipeCell.recipe = recipes[indexPath.item]

    return recipeCell
}



override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)

    collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}

}

class RecipeCell: UICollectionViewCell {

var recipe: BrowsableRecipe? {
    didSet {

        if let name = recipe?.recipeName {

            let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: name, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(14)])
            nameLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            print("in did set")
            nameLabel.attributedText = attributedText

        }


    }
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    setupViews()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

let nameLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.numberOfLines = 2



    return label
}()



func setupViews() {
    backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    addSubview(nameLabel)

    addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|-12-[v0]", views: nameLabel)

}

}

 extension UIColor {

static func rgb(red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat) -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red: red/255, green: green/255, blue: blue/255, alpha: 1)
}

}

extension UIView {

func addConstraintsWithFormat(format: String, views: UIView...) {
    var viewsDictionary = [String: UIView]()
    for (index, view) in views.enumerate() {
        let key = "v\(index)"
        viewsDictionary[key] = view
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
}

}
```

The reason why no content displays in this `collectionView` I am sure directly stems from the fact that `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is never called (I tested with print statements)

Any help Appreciated.

For Reference, 
here is the project I used as a starting point 
https://github.com/purelyswift/facebook_feed_dynamic_cell_content

---

UPDATE:

I tried doing this with `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths` in my async call back:

and I get

```
reason: 'attempt to delete item 9 from section 0 which only contains 0 items before the update'
```

which suggested I need to add something to section 0 first. so then I try:

```
     self.collectionView!.insertItemsAtIndexPaths(myArrayOfIndexPaths)
```

And I get:

```
 reason: 'no UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes instance for -layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call reload data after you set data array. Coz system call for realod will call before you have set the data array

```
if let data = responseObject{

        self.recipes = data
        print(self.recipes)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {  // if you are setting in different thread
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

if not check if it is calling 'numberOfItemsInSection' method. If not probably you havent set the dataSource and delegate.